# How to find Geocoordinate using address in WINDOWS 8 store application C# bing map

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps

I want to display push pin on bing map,i have address lists and i want GeoCoordinate of that addresses how can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dedicated REST services like described on the MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

In order to improve the performance, I would recommend to make sure that you already have geocoded them before displaying them on the map so you would only have to add them on the map control.

Also, since you're in Windows 8 and C# application, you should have a look at Ricky's blog here, where you will be able to find a sample application as well as some useful proxy classes to ease the use of the services through .Net application: 
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/geocoding-and-routing-in-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-native/